# How to push Value in an array exist inside in an object of state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, javascript-objects, react-state-management

I'm new to React and working on a project of comments nesting as we see in facebook and youtube comments section.
I have created states to manage nesting.
This is a single comment state:

`const [comment, setComment] = useState({author:"", desc:"",replies:[]});`

I'm managing the list of comments in an array:

`const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);`

I have managed to add or remove the comment from comments state like this:

```
const addComment=()=>{
     if(comment.desc !== ""){
      setComments((prevComments)=>{
        return  [...prevComments, comment]
      });
      setComment({author:"", desc:"", replies:[]});
      setIsCommentVisible(true);
     }
   }


   const removeComment=(id)=>{
      setComments((prevComments)=>{
       return prevComments.filter((val, ind)=> ind !==id);
      });
   }
```

but I am having a problem in adding a reply in an array of objects into its replies property which is also an array.

So I want to know the approach to get a specific comment by its id and push a reply into its replies property.

```
//This is what I have tried
 const addReply=(id, reply)=>{
    setComments((prevComments)=>{
      return [...prevComments, /*So what's the approach here how to get
 access to the specific indexed replies property and push a reply into it.*/]
    });
   }
```

Comment: In react you should shallow copy/merge all state updates. What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Where do the `comments` array `comment` objects have an `id` property to match by?

Comment: actualy id is the key of a single comment in my CommentList component Im passing the addReply function as a prop to the CommentList Component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sort of looks like you are using the current index to update state.

Shallow copy the state, and any nested state, that is being updated. Use the `id` to match to the currently mapped comment state, and when you are on the comment you want to update, shallow copy the comment and update the `replies` property by appending the `reply` and returning a new array reference.

```
const addReply = (id, reply) => {
  setComments(prevComments => prevComments.map(
    (comment, index) => index === id 
      ? {
        ...comment,
        replies: comment.replies.concat(reply)
      }
      : comment
    )
  );
}
```

Ideally your `comment` objects would have a GUID assigned to them, this way it's easier to match them independently of any array sorted order or any other issues that pop up when mutating arrays in React.

Example:

```
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from 'uuid';

...

const addComment = () => {
  if (comment.desc !== "") {
    setComments((prevComments) => {
      return [...prevComments, { ...comment, id: uuidV4() }]
    });
    setComment({ author: "", desc: "", replies: [] });
    setIsCommentVisible(true);
  }
} 

const addReply = (id, reply) => {
  setComments(prevComments => prevComments.map(
    (comment) => comment.id === id 
      ? {
        ...comment,
        replies: comment.replies.concat(reply)
      }
      : comment
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Drew Reese for the solution it worked. One thing I want to know is you have used a uuid library I'm not familiar with it so intead of ```prevComments.map((comment)=> comment.id === id)``` I have used  ```prevComments.map((comment, index)=> index === id)``` is this approach Good?

Comment: One more question why you have used ```concat()``` instead of  ```push()``` ?

Comment: @IbrahimAhmed I would say it's not ideal since array indices don't uniquely identify a specific array element object. The second half of my answer attempts to explain why. `uuid` is just a package to generate unique id's. It's handy if the data source you're using doesn't provide a unique id property. Ideally you'll want stable GUIDs for the life of the element in the React component lifecycle, i.e. from mount to unmount, and possibly longer if storing in app state like redux.

Comment: @IbrahimAhmed That's a great question. `.push` mutates the array it functions on. We use `.concat` to add an array or element to an existing array ***and*** return a new array. You could also use the Spread syntax, i.e. `[...comment.replies, reply]` to copy the previous state, add reply, and return a new array.

Comment: thank you so much for the explanations you have made my day and I have learnt something new. :-)